# rbokeh, add legend to histogram plot

Tags: r, htmlwidgets, rbokeh

I'd like to make a chart with `rbokeh` that includes three overlapping histograms. I can do this, but no legend appears:

```
library(rbokeh)

figure(tools=c(), legend_location="top_right", padding_factor = 0.01) %>% 
  ly_hist(rnorm(10000, mean=0), 
          color=color_palette[1], alpha = 0.3, breaks=20, lname="L", legend="L", freq=F) %>%
  ly_hist(rnorm(10000, mean=1, sd=0.25), 
          color=color_palette[2], alpha = 0.3, breaks=20, lname="M", legend="M", freq=F) %>%
  ly_hist(rnorm(10000, mean=2, sd=0.5), 
          color=color_palette[3], alpha = 0.3, breaks=20, lname="H", legend="H", freq=F)
```

If I was using base R, I would need to call `legend()` explicitly, as in
[Adding key legend to multi-histogram plot in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14683766/adding-key-legend-to-multi-histogram-plot-in-r)

I don't see an `rbokeh::legend()` function.

Can anyone advise how to add a legend to the plot?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not seeing legend in the documentation for `ly_hist`. I think your best shot would be using `ly_text` and manually adding a legend.